# Setting message priority in RabbitMQ PHP

Tags: php, rabbitmq, message-queue

I've found plenty of examples of setting message priority in RabbitMQ for Java, Spring, etc. but so far I haven't found how to implement this in PHP.

In fact the `$channel->basic_publish()` function doesn't appear to support supplying additional parameters (https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php), even though you can do this in the RabbitMQ gui.

Has anyone got message priorities working with RabbitMQ in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, it was staring me in the face the whole time. You set the priority in the actual `message` object, not when you push it into the queue:

```
$msg = new AMQPMessage("Hello World!", array(
    'delivery_mode' => 2,
    'priority' => 1,
    'timestamp' => time(),
    'expiration' => strval(1000 * (strtotime('+1 day midnight') - time() - 1))
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for [AMQP Interop](https://github.com/queue-interop/queue-interop#amqp-interop). Pay attention that you should not only set a priority header but a special argument while declaring a queue.

Install AMQP Interop compatible transport, for example

```
composer require enqueue/amqp-bunny
```

And do next:

```
<?php
use Enqueue\AmqpBunny\AmqpConnectionFactory;
use Interop\Amqp\AmqpQueue;

$context = (new AmqpConnectionFactory())->createContext(); // connects to localhost with defaults

$queue = $context->createQueue("transcode2");
$queue->addFlag(AmqpQueue::FLAG_PASSIVE);
$queue->setArgument('x-max-priority', 10);
$context->declareQueue($queue);

$message = $context->createMessage(json_encode($msg));
$message->setPriority(5);

$producer = $context->createProducer($queue, $message);

$producer->send($queue, $message);
```